# Asp .Net Core Download Report from SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, asp.net-core-2.2

I have been trying hard to get a report from SSRS but seems like it is not supported in .Net Core. So I would like to know if is there a way to just download the report on browser in Asp .Net Core with parameters? All i need is to download it, no need to preview it with report view since there is no compatibility for this.

User clicks a button and parameters are sent through controller or razor page and just need a way to get report and download on browser

Comment: You can render a report directly to a supported file type (Excel PDF, Word etc) including all it's parameters via a URL.
Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/export-a-report-using-url-access?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a lot of work and avoiding dealing with web forms again!

Answer (score 2):

According to microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/export-a-report-using-url-access?view=sql-server-2017), you need to first generate **url** according to your ssrs report & parameter as following...

```
https://servername/ReportServer_THESQLINSTANCE/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2freportfolder%2freport+name+with+spaces&rs:Format=pdf
```

then pass this url to the following Controller Action....

```
    public IActionResult GetReportingData(string url)
    {
        try
        {                
            url = url.Replace("\n", "");
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);           

            NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"**UserName*", "***Password***");
            request.Credentials = credentials;

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

            return File(stream, "application/pdf");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

this action will return/download a pdf file as you required.