# SSRS Reports with .Net Core

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, reporting-services, impersonation

I am trying to figure out the best way to connect to SSRS to retrieve some reports. I had a look at WSDL (SOAP) and REST endpoints and so far the seem good. Also on stackoverflow there was a simple solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56492683/asp-net-core-download-report-from-ssrs) and of course there is more.

What I want to do is being able to impersonate AD users when getting reports. But it would be great to be able to impersonate a user *without* using his/her password. I red about custom security implementations but I didn't really see if this would be helpful (I'm new to this).

I have a single sign on Asp.Net Core application with an angular js frontend. *I would like the backend to get the reports* and provide them to the frontend. Here are my questions:

- Whats's the best way for a .Net Core Application to connect to the SSRS server? Is it WSDL (SOAP) or REST or something else?
- Can I impersonate an AD user without his/her password? Do I always have to use username and password for this?

I couldn't realy find anything that I could apply to my solution. Creating a custom security seemd time consuming but maybe it's part of the solution.

Help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: In short: What's the best way to connect to SSRS from ASP.Net Core?

Comment: regarding the impersonation: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/5021